# accessing stdin/stdout of a process started in another tty

Tags: linux, ssh, process, console, tty

I logged in to my linux physically(say tty1) and started a process that watches stdin for commands and has some stdout-put. How can I access/use this process from a SSH session?

Comment: You should use `tmux` or `screen` and attach to the running session from ssh

Comment: See [these other questions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=reptyr)

Answer (score 0):

You can send output directly into another terminal using the device files under `/dev`. For example:

```
echo "my command" > /dev/tty1
```

to send output to `tty1` or

```
echo "my command" > /dev/pts/0
```

to send output to the first pseudo-terminal. Use the `ps` command to see what terminal a process is running on.

Comment: did you mean `echo` instead of `cat`?

Comment: @rodvlopes I did. Good catch, I'm not sure how this went so long without being noticed.

Comment: This approach sends characters to the terminal, not to the process running in the terminal. See https://serverfault.com/questions/178457/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-running-in-a-screen-sessi/178470